# Print Metrics RNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I was wondering if it is possible to print the metrics of a RNN, verbose just shows me just shows me a simplified number, for examle "0.0014" but I wanted toprint the full final value. I wanted to print the metrics(mse) final value

Here is a Code for my model:

```
# creating model using Keras
model10 = Sequential()
model10.add(GRU(units=120, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(1,12),activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0005)))
model10.add(GRU(units=80, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.1))
model10.add(GRU(units=40, dropout=0.1))
model10.add(Dense(units=5))
model10.add(Dense(units=3))
model10.add(Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))
model10.compile(loss=['mae'], optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0005),metrics=['mse']) 
model10.summary() 


history10=model10.fit(X10_train, y10_train, batch_size=1000,epochs=20,validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc),Early_Stop])
```

Thank you.

Comment: could you provide an example

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat sorry provide and example of? I want to print the `metrics=['mse'] ` final value.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by final value,do you mean the last value of the `mse` when the training end?if that so,try this `history10.history10['mse'][-1]`

Comment: Yes the final value of the mse when training ends, thank you I will try this now.

Comment: if it works for you,I will add it to the answer

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat unfortunatly, that didn't work

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: `ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your final MSE value, try:

```
history10.history['mean_squared_error'][-1]
```

And to get the entire history, so the values for each epoch, try:

```
history10.history['mean_squared_error']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, it appears tensorboard values are slightly off though theya re not exactly the same.